# Downloading a Private Access file from Google drive via API

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to download a private access file from Google drive via api?

The reason I want this is to prevent people from sharing the download link because I want to provide files for paid customer only.

If its not what are my option to provide file download only for paid customers and preventing them from sharing those download links with others?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set scopes for your users to restrict the level of access. See [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file).

> Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content. For example, an app using the drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by read-only users by setting the viewersCanCopyContent field to true.

You may also want to look at [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) especially the `viewersCanCopyContent`.

> **viewersCanCopyContent**
>
> **boolean**
>
> Whether users with only reader or commenter permission can copy the file's content. This affects copy, download, and print operations.